# "invalid_grant" error while trying to use Discord's oauth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord

```
const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: redirectURL,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code,
  }),
});
```

When I run the above code, it returns with `{ error: 'invalid_grant' }` and I do not know why. Are there any fixes to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, all I had to do was to use `querystring` instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you also need to send the scope param as per the docs:

```
const data = {

        client_id: 'your client id',
        client_secret: 'your client secret',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: 'your redirect uri',
        code: accessCode,
        scope: 'the scopes',
    };
    
    fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new URLSearchParams(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log);
```

You need to send your body as URLSearchParams(data).

You also need to add this at the top of your code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Check this new link:

https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#oauth2-flows

Comment: I passed the scope in and still no avail.
https://sourceb.in/PRFno2AVqi

Comment: The same error as before, `{ error: 'invalid_grant' }`

Comment: I fixed it, all I had to do was to use querystring instead of JSON.